# have to encode by HTML link with base64

Tags: javascript, html, forms

It is my first post and hope it won't be already solved previously.
I'm using a call center software and also using Salesforce lightning.

When a caller calls, I would like to check in my CRM if it is a customer or not.
It was possible easily with the basic version of Salesforce but is not anymore because the link is coded with base64.
Please, read this post for more explanation : https://tomsmalara.blogspot.com/2019/01/create-lightning-component-that.html

So, I have to create a HTML page for collecting the caller phone number and compose + encrypt the Salesforce link and open the link encrypted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Waiting a call ...</title>
   <style> 
    body {text-align: center;} 
   </style> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="form1" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return displayResult();">
   <label for="name">Phone number:</label>
   <input type="text" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" size="10">
   <div id="myEncoding"></div>
  </form> 
  <script>
   function b64EncodeUnicode(PhoneNumber) {
    // first we use encodeURIComponent to get percent-encoded UTF-8,
    // then we convert the percent encodings into raw bytes which
    // can be fed into btoa.
    
    var Mytxt = '{"componentDef":"forceSearch:search","attributes":{"term":"'+PhoneNumber+'","scopeMap":{"resultsCmp":"forceSearch:resultsTopResults","label":"Top Results","type":"TOP_RESULTS","cacheable":"Y","id":"TOP_RESULTS","labelPlural":"Top Results"},"context":{"disableSpellCorrection":false,"SEARCH_ACTIVITY":{"term":1234567890}}},"state":{}}';
    
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(Mytxt).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
     function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
      var MyResult = String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
      return MyResult;
    }));
   }

   function displayResult() {
    var result = b64EncodeUnicode(PhoneNumber);
    document.getElementById('myEncoding').innerHTML = result;
    return false;
    window.open("https://mycompany.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#" +result,,,true)
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Something is wrong and tried different things without result.
I will really appreciate if someone can find what is wrong and explain it to me
Thank you in advance

Comment: You are now [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your `JSON`, then replacing all percent-encoded parts with their byte value (which does not need the '0x' prefix, and is incorrect for multi-byte values), and finally encode all that to `BASE64`. According to the explanation you linked, you just need to `BASE64` encode your `JSON` string. So something like: `return btoa(Mytxt);`. Only thing left then is to sanitize your input (`PhoneNumber`). Please also note that the example has `source=alohaHeader` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

PLease find the solution I found to remove the input steps ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Waiting a call ...</title>
   <style> 
    body {text-align: center;} 
   </style> 
 </head>
 <body onload=acceptParam()>
  Waiting a call ...

  <script> 
   function acceptParam(){
     var hashParams = window.location.href.substr(1).split('?'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
     hashParams = hashParams[1].split('&');
     var p = hashParams[0].split('=');
     //document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value = p[1] // Pour info
     
     var stringToEncode = '{"componentDef":"forceSearch:searchPage","attributes":{"term":"'+p[1]+'","scopeMap":{"type":"TOP_RESULTS"},"context":{"disableSpellCorrection":false,"disableIntentQuery":false,"permsAndPrefs":{"SearchUi.searchUIPilotFeatureEnabled":false,"SearchExperience.LeftNavEnhancementEnabled":true,"Search.crossObjectsAutoSuggestEnabled":true,"SearchResultsLVM.lvmEnabledForSearchResultsOn":true,"MySearch.userCanHaveMySearchBestResult":false,"SearchResultsLVM.lvmEnabledForTopResults":false,"OrgPermissions.UnionAppNavSmartScope":false,"SearchUi.feedbackComponentEnabled":false,"SearchExperience.TopResultsSingleSOSLEnabled":false,"OrgPreferences.ChatterEnabled":true,"Search.maskSearchInfoInLogs":false,"SearchUi.orgHasAccessToSearchTermHistory":false,"SearchUi.searchUIInteractionLoggingEnabled":false,"MySearch.userCanHaveMySearch":false},"searchDialogSessionId":"bdded2dc-91d1-3b3e-11d7-ff339bce1727","searchSource":"INPUT_DESKTOP"},"groupId":"DEFAULT"},"state":{}}'
     var encoded = window.btoa(stringToEncode); 
   
     //var output = "Encoded String : " + encoded; 
     //document.getElementById("myEncoding").innerHTML = "Original String: " + p[1] + "<br>" + output; 
     window.location.assign("https://mycompany.lightning.force.com/lightning/one/one.app?source=alohaHeader#"+encoded);
   } 
    </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

PLease, can you say me what do you think about it ? Maybe we can be more efficient ?

Comment: Please do not put questions in answers, instead create a new question. Questions about efficiency are off-topic on StackOverflow and would better fit on [codereview.stackexchange.com](//codereview.stackexchange.com)